# PDO - Something is not quite right with my statement 'Undefined class constant 'PARAM_STRING''

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am new to PDO and have managed to get some  statements working, but now I am trying to work with a 'string' and am getting an error message. Clearly I'm doing something wrong here.

I get this error message:

Undefined class constant 'PARAM_STRING'

here is my code:

```
require_once('../scripts/includePDO.php');

$who = 65; //temp value to be deleted
$status = $_POST['status'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_status(from_user, status, deleted) VALUES (:who, :status, '0')";

$q   =  $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->bindValue(':who',$who,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $q->bindValue(':status',$status,PDO::PARAM_STRING);
        $q->execute();

header("Location: ../home/");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDO::PARAM_STRING is incorrect, you need to use `PDO::PARAM_STR` instead.

Comment: Correct answer!
Can I also ask, is my coding here actually doing anything? I'm trying to prevent SQL injection. My code works from the point of, it executes correctly - But can people still SQL inject it?

Comment: No, that's the whole idea with binding parameters and values. The query is set up first and then the data is passed to the query, injection is impossible.

Comment: Super! And finally, does this mean that it is OK to perform statements that use 'SELECT * FROM table_name' as long as using PDO within that? I hear that you should never really use SELECT * FROM when it's not completely necessary.

Comment: @ElaineAdams: Yes, everything wrapped in PDO will be safe and stick with named fields in a SELECT unless you absolutely require everything from the db. I've also given you an upvote too - just for using PDO and actually being concerned about injection!

Comment: While I noticed your answer right away from the question, *my* problem is that I'm getting `Undefined class constant 'PARAM_STR'` -- so **now** what?!  :)

Comment: @Olie: Which PHP version are you using? [PDO only uses class constants since PHP 5.1 ...](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php). You can actually leave the datatype out altogether as it's [optional](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), PDO will work it out for itself - `$q->bindValue(':status',$status);`.

Comment: TBD: I ended up using the shorter format, though my PHP is 5.4.30, so I'd-a thought this *should* work!  Now I'm just sort of curious why I'm getting the area as a matter of curiosity, since my actual "problem" is solved.

Comment: My PHP version is `PHP Version 7.3.30` and I am using the statement `Yii::$app->sds->createCommand("select CustomerCode, CustomerNameFull
,AreaCode,AreaNameFull,CityNameFull
,ContactPerson,Address1,MobileNumber
from Customers
where AreaCode = :area_ids")->bindValues([':area_ids'=>$area_ids,PDO::PARAM_STR])->queryAll();`

Comment: The above statement gives me an error now `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based\nFailed to prepare SQL`

Comment: I have tried your solution but still, it's not working for me can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72976023/6854117)?