# Yii2 Mssql Unknown PDO::PARAM_* constant given

Tags: php, sql, pdo, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `Yii2`. I have added an `MSSQL Database`. For preventing from SQL injections please see my below is my query

```
$area_ids = [];
    $s = AllowArea::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->all();

    foreach ($s as $b) {
        $area_ids[] = $b->area_code;
    }

    $ref = Yii::$app->sds->createCommand("select CustomerCode, CustomerNameFull
          ,AreaCode,AreaNameFull,CityNameFull
          ,ContactPerson,Address1,MobileNumber
          from Customers
          where AreaCode = :area_ids")->bindValues([':area_ids'=>$area_ids])->queryAll();
```

When I execute it I am getting

```
{
"name": "PHP Fatal Error",
"message": "Unknown PDO::PARAM_* constant given.",
"code": 1,
"type": "yii\\base\\ErrorException",
"file": "G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php",
"line": 1290,
"stack-trace": [
    "#0 [internal function]: yii\\base\\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()",
    "#1 {main}"
     ]
}
```

After checking this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21831565/6854117) I have done the following

```
->bindValues([':area_ids'=>$area_ids,PDO::PARAM_STR])
```

Now I get

```
{
"name": "Database Exception",
"message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based\nFailed to prepare SQL: select CustomerCode, CustomerNameFull\r\n,AreaCode,AreaNameFull,CityNameFull\r\n,ContactPerson,Address1,MobileNumber\r\nfrom Customers\r\nwhere AreaCode = :area_ids",
"code": 0,
"type": "yii\\db\\Exception",
"file": "G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php",
"line": 264,
"stack-trace": [
    "#0 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php(1153): yii\\db\\Command->prepare(true)",
    "#1 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php(399): yii\\db\\Command->queryInternal('fetchAll', NULL)",
    "#2 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\api\\modules\\v1\\controllers\\RoutesController.php(400): yii\\db\\Command->queryAll()",
    "#3 [internal function]: api\\modules\\v1\\controllers\\RoutesController->actionRefs()",
    "#4 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
    "#5 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Controller.php(157): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)",
    "#6 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Module.php(528): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('refs', Array)",
    "#7 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\Application.php(103): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('v1/routes/refs', Array)",
    "#8 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Application.php(386): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))",
    "#9 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\api\\web\\index.php(35): yii\\base\\Application->run()",
    "#10 {main}"
],
"error-info": [
    "HY093",
    0
],
"previous": {
    "name": "Exception",
    "message": "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based",
    "code": "HY093",
    "type": "PDOException",
    "file": "G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php",
    "line": 316,
    "stack-trace": [
        "#0 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php(316): PDOStatement->bindValue(0, 2, 1)",
        "#1 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php(260): yii\\db\\Command->bindPendingParams()",
        "#2 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php(1153): yii\\db\\Command->prepare(true)",
        "#3 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\db\\Command.php(399): yii\\db\\Command->queryInternal('fetchAll', NULL)",
        "#4 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\api\\modules\\v1\\controllers\\RoutesController.php(400): yii\\db\\Command->queryAll()",
        "#5 [internal function]: api\\modules\\v1\\controllers\\RoutesController->actionRefs()",
        "#6 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)",
        "#7 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Controller.php(157): yii\\base\\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)",
        "#8 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Module.php(528): yii\\base\\Controller->runAction('refs', Array)",
        "#9 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\web\\Application.php(103): yii\\base\\Module->runAction('v1/routes/refs', Array)",
        "#10 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\vendor\\yiisoft\\yii2\\base\\Application.php(386): yii\\web\\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\\web\\Request))",
        "#11 G:\\xampp\\htdocs\\wrfnan\\api\\web\\index.php(35): yii\\base\\Application->run()",
        "#12 {main}"
    ]
}
}
```

I must be missing something that I don't know. How to get this issue resolved?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Note:** `$area_ids` is the array

Comment: MsSQL does not support array types. Only PostgreSQL supports those, and not through the PHP driver.

Comment: @coladict ok so is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Compile a `value in (?, ?, ?, ?...)` query and bind positional parameters.

Comment: Can you pl share the snipt ?

Comment: @coladict i have updated the code to `where AreaCode in :area_ids")->bindValues([':area_ids'=>$area_ids])->queryAll()`. but still getting the same error

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I haven't really touched PHP this year. I posted an answer as to what I've done in the past from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just let [query builder](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder) take care of it for you.

```php
$ref = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'CustomerCode',
        'CustomerNameFull',
        'AreaCode',
        'AreaNameFull',
        'CityNameFull',
        'ContactPerson',
        'Address1',
        'MobileNumber'
    ])->from('Customers')
    ->where(['AreaCode' => $area_$ids])
    ->all(Yii::$app->sds);
```

The query builder uses param binding internally so you don't have to worry about SQL injection.

**Side note:**
You don't need to load all AllowArea models just to get the list of area codes in cycle from them. You can do it like this:

```php
$area_ids = AllowArea::find()
    ->select(['area_code'])
    ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
    ->column();
```

The [`column()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#column()-detail) method returns first selected column as array.

Comment: The best solution so far

Answer (score 0):

The pattern I employ in these situations is this:

```
$params = []; // positional only

// add any preceding parameters to it

$qmarks = [];

foreach ($area_ids as $id) {
    $params[] = $id;
    $qmarks[] = '?';
}

$queryStr = 'SELECT... WHERE some_id IN (' . implode(',', $qmarks) . ')';

$stmt = Yii::$app->sds->createCommand($queryStr); // though I use PDO directly, this is close enough
$indBase = 1; // base. if we have preceding parameters it must be higher
foreach ($params as $ind => $param) {
    $stmt->bindValue($indBase + $ind, $param);
}
$ref = $stmt->queryAll();
```

Please note: if your `$area_ids` array is empty, this will result in `some_id IN ()` which is invalid syntax in nearly all SQL databases. You have to either remove that condition, or decide whether you need to call the query at all.

Comment: `$area_ids = [];
        $s = AllowArea::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])->all();

        foreach ($s as $b) {
            $area_ids[] = $b->area_code;
        }

        $params = []; // positional only
        // add any preceding parameters to it

        $qmarks = [];

        $id = [];
        foreach ($id as $area_ids) {
            $params[] = $id;
            $qmarks[] = '?';
        }`

Comment: `var_dump($queryStr); die();` gives me `select CustomerCode, CustomerNameFull
,AreaCode,AreaNameFull,CityNameFull
,ContactPerson,Address1,MobileNumber
from Customers
where AreaCode IN ()`

Comment: the `IN` part is empty

Comment: area_ids does have date in it`array(47) {
[0]=>
string(7) "0216007"
[1]=>
string(7) "0216020"
[2]=>
string(7) "0216019"}`

Comment: Also the `$id` is empty

Comment: I had written `foreach ($id as $area_ids)` instead of `foreach ($area_ids as $id)` because I've been away from PHP and have been working with Java. Simple mistake you could have caught.